# Proper way to test Chalice app with env variables

Tags: pytest, chalice

I have a Chalice API project with the following config under `.chalice/config.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "app_name": "my-app",
  "manage_iam_role": true,
  "stages": {
    "local": {
      "api_gateway_stage": "local",
      "environment_variables": {
        "STAGE_NAME": "local",
        "MY_ENV_VAR": "value-local"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "api_gateway_stage": "stg",
      "environment_variables": {
        "STAGE_NAME": "staging",
        "MY_ENV_VAR": "value-staging"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "api_gateway_stage": "prod",
      "environment_variables": {
        "STAGE_NAME": "production",
        "MY_ENV_VAR": "value-prod"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The app code uses some env variables like `MY_ENV_VAR`, loaded with `os.environ["MY_ENV_VAR"]`.

The tests look like the following (let's say in a `tests/test_my_endpoint.py` file):

```
from http import HTTPStatus

from app import app
from chalice.test import Client

def test_my_endpoint() -> None:
    with Client(app, stage_name="local") as client:
        response = client.http.get("/my-endpoint")
        assert response.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK
```

But it seems `stage_name="local"` doesn't mean variables for the stage `local` are loaded for the tests, so during tests execution, env variables are not found and tests fail. I'm not sure how setting this argument for `chalice.test.Client` is useful then.

For testing locally, I can always load environment variables locally, but for CI/CD, I would like the tests to use the env variable of a stage defined in `.chalice/config.json`. Chalice documentation isn't very clear about the good practice here, and about how `stage_name` argument works exactly.

How can I fix that, and generally speaking what is the proper way to create tests for a Chalice app using the env variables?